# Clearing all activities with intent filters is not calling any destroy methods

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack, android-ondestroy

When a user logs out in my app I want to take them to the login screen and clear the current stack. To do this I call this code with my intent, and it works:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```

**However**, none of my fragments or activities that are being cleared have their destroy methods called. How do I get these methods called?

Answer (score 0):

My method was working all along. The issue turned out to be a crash that I thought was happening when getting to the new screen. But it was happening before I even started it, and it stopped the destroy method from being called.